# Delphi Metro App in Tablet with Windows 10 home edition

Tags: delphi, microsoft-metro, tablet

I need to create a delphi app to install and run into a Tablet with Windows 10 - home edition.

If I use Delphi XE8/Win 8.1 and create a Metropolis or VCL app, could I be able to install it into that Tablet and run without problem?

If is not possible, what type of app could I create with Delphi XE8/Win 8.1 to run into a windows 10 tablet - home edition?

For now I didn´t buy the tablet because I don´t know if the app will work.

Luiz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time, Delphi cannot produce *true* Universal (formerly known as Metro) apps. It can only produce native Win32 apps that *look and feel* like Universal apps (and can access a few select WinRT APIs that have been made accessible to Win32), but they are not *true* Universal apps from Windows' perspective.

So, Delphi cannot be used to develop apps that can be deployed through the Windows App store (at least until Microsoft releases its "Project Centennial" bridge, which is essentially just a Universal wrapper for Win32 apps).

That being said, the Windows 10 *Mobile* OS (for phones and small tablets) cannot (yet) run native Win32 apps, only Universal apps.  On tablets with a screen size of 8" or larger, tablet manufacturers *may* decide to install the full Windows 10 desktop OS instead, in which case native Win32 apps can be run.

Comment: Mr Remy, the tablet I intent to buy will have windows 10 home edition. For this version of windows, there is no problem to run win32 native app, is it correct?

Comment: @LuizAlves `manufacturers may decide to install the full Windows 10 desktop OS instead, in which case native Win32 apps can be run.` Windows 10 home edition is desktop OS,And the answer **yes that's correct** .

Comment: @RepeatUntil Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can create an application with delphi (VCL or FMX) that run without problems in a Windows 10. In a desktop computer, in a portatil or a Tablet.
The problem not is the device, is the operating system installed.

You can't develop for Windows 10 Movile, but without problem for Windows 10 Home Edition.

I have developed for a Tablet with Windows 10 with Delphi 7 (and DevExpress for Metro interface). Of course you can do it with Delphi XE8.

Regards.

Comment: @Mr Neftali, then win32 app developed with XE8 will work in tablet with windows 10 home edition, OK? I live in Brazil and all of tablets with windows 10 for sale comes with home edition. No Pro or enterpise version for now. With Windows 10 home edition can I install a win32 app from a sd card?

Comment: If this application work on a PC with Windows 10 Home Edition, will work on a tablet with Windows 10 Home Edition.